# If 1st day Shavuot occurred on Shabbat, could you begin early?

Tags: shabbat, sefirat-ha-omer, shavuos

With the fixed calendar, now, the 1st day of Shavuot never occurs on Shabbat. On the 1st night of Shavu'ot many congregations wait to daven Ma'ariv until *tzet* so that the Omer counting should be *tamim* - i.e., there should be a full 49 days of Omer.

However, it is allowable to begin Shabbat early. If the 1st day of Shavuot could occur on Shabbat, would this fact override the rule of waiting for *tzet* on Shavuot because of *temimut*?

Comment: Who says you can't begin Shavuos early on a weekday?

Comment: @Yehoshua - You're coming in late on the discussion, as I had edited some parts out of this question. In brief, I'm not saying that you can't do it. I'm saying that many congregations don't do it b/c of the *temimut* concern. See the answer as well as my subsequent comments, below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [yeshiva.org.il](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/20381) who writes

> חג השבועות
>
> יב. בליל שבועות אין מתפללין ערבית מבעו"י, אלא מאחרין להתפלל בצאת
>   הכוכבים כדי שיהיו ימי הספירה מ"ט יום תמימות (מ"ב תצד ס"ק ד). וכן
>   נוהגים בקהילות רבות,
>
> אמנם בקהילות אשכנזיות מסויימות נוהגים להתפלל
>   ערבית ולקדש מבעו"י אף בליל שבועות,
>
> ויש קהילות שמתפללים ערבית מבעו"י
>   וממתינים עם הקידוש עד צאת הכוכבים (ראה בהרחבה ובפירוט בספר שרשי מנהג
>   אשכנז חלק ד עמוד 344 ובספר הלכות חג בחג על חג השבועות פרק ח אות יז
>   והערה 34). בערוה"ש (סימן תצד סעיף ג) כתב, בליל שבועות אין מקדשין על
>   הכוס עד שתהא לילה ממש משום תמימות כלומר שהספירה תושלם בתמימות [משמע
>   דדעתו כדעה השלישית דממתינים עם הקידוש עד צאה"כ אבל ערבית יכול להתפלל
>   מבעו"י
>
> Summary: These principles apply even on weekdays. There are three
>   views:
>
> 1) On the night of Shavuos one should not daven maariv until
>   night.
>
> 2) Certain Ashkenazi communities  daven maariv and make kiddush
>   before night.
>
> 3) Other communities  daven maariv before night but make
>   kiddush only after nightfall. The text of the [Oruch Hashulchan 494
>   (3)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A6%D7%93) implies that he agrees with this last view.

So, it is permitted to daven maariv before night on Shavuos even on a weekday. Btw, our shul follows the third view above.

ADDITION

There is a mitzvoh of adding to Shabbos from the weekday. 
See [Pninei Halocho Rav Melamed](http://ph.yhb.org.il/01-03-02/#ref_3_3_2)

> מצד הקדושה הקבועה של השבת, רק בעת שהיום השביעי מתחיל, השבת נכנסת, אלא
>   **שמצווה מהתורה**, להוסיף מהחול על הקודש. כלומר, שנקבל אנחנו על עצמנו את
>   קדושת השבת מעט קודם כניסת היום השביעי.
>
> The holiness of Shabbos starts only when the 7th day starts. But there
>   is a  **Torah mitzvoh** to add to the holy from the mundane. That means
>   that we accept on ourselves the holiness of Shabbos before  the 7th
>   day starts.

Waiting to daven Ma'ariv until tzet so that the Omer counting should be tamim, is suggested by the Torah text but, as we see from the discussion above, is not accepted by everybody and therefore presumably is not  a Torah mitzvoh.

Therefore there is a reason to say that bringing in Shabbos early should take precedence over waiting to daven Ma'ariv until tzet  on the night of Shavuos.

Comment: While the question is pretty poor for other reasons above, it seems clear he's asking if the opinions that don't let you take in shavout early would feel differently if Shavuot were on Shabbat. Not if anyone allows early Shavuot in general (which is of course yes namely all rishonim and the shulchan Arukh and rama!!)

Comment: @DoubleAA I respect your understanding of the question and I agree that I do not answer according to the view that you must wait to daven Ma'ariv until tzet.

Comment: This is a good answer to  (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8066/5275). Can you transfer your answer to there?

Comment: @DanF I have used the insufficient answer as the basis for my edited (and hopefully improved) attempt to answer your interesting question.

Comment: Is there no Torah Mitzva to add to Yom Tov like Shabbat? The Gemara seems to equate them

Comment: Besides @DoubleAA's question. above (excellent point, BTW!) I would argue that by beginning Shabbat early when Yom Tov is on Shabbat, one is accomplishing both Tosefet Shabbat and Yom Tov simultaneously. What's unclear from your answer, still, is whether the Tosefet rule overrides the temimut rule. This seems to be an area unique to Shavuot. I would further argue, based on your assumption that if Tosefet Yom Tov is not Torah based but, clearly temimut is, then, the entire idea of davening early on Yom Tov would be prohibited b/c you're violating a Torah rule!

Comment: @DanF I do not understand/agree with your comment. (1) I maintain that the implication from temimus that maariv starts at tzais is **not** a Torah mitzvah because there are those who disagree with the need to daven maariv at that time. (2) I made no statements about Tosefes Yom Tov because your question was about the 1st day of Shavuos occuring  on Shabbos.